# NSData means what? how to implements its characterstics in java?

Tags: java, iphone, android

NSData means what? how to implements its characterstics in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSData is an array of bytes with flexible size (for the mutable version).

(I guess the corresponding Java type is `byte[]`.)

Comment: byte[] is immutable